# Why is this always printing the first if statement and nothing else?

Tags: python

```
grade = raw_input("What was your score?")

if grade >= 93:
  print "For a score of " + grade + ", your grade is an A"
elif grade >= 90 and grade < 93:
  print "For a score of " + grade + ", your grade is an A-"
elif grade >= 87 and grade < 90:
  print "For a score of " + grade + ", your grade is a B+"
elif grade >= 83 and grade < 87:
  print "For a score of " + grade + ", your grade is a B"
elif grade >= 80 and grade < 83:
  print "For a score of " + grade + ", your grade is a B-"
elif grade >= 77 and grade < 80:
  print "For a score of " + grade + ", your grade is a C+"
elif grade >= 73 and grade < 77:
  print "For a score of " + grade + ", your grade is a C"
elif grade >= 70 and grade < 73:
  print "For a score of " + grade + ", your grade is a C-"
elif grade >= 67 and grade < 70:
  print "For a score of " + grade + ", your grade is a D+"
elif grade >= 63 and grade < 67:
  print "For a score of " + grade + ", your grade is a D"
elif grade >= 60 and grade < 63:
  print "For a score of " + grade + ", your grade is a D-"
else:
  print "For a score of " + grade + ", your grade is an F"
```

No matter what is entered as raw input, the statement printed is always "For a score of ___, your grade is an A" even if it should be a B or a D or anything else

Comment: Because you are comparing a string and an integer. If you were using Python 3 (as you should) you'd have found it out yourself (unlike Python 2, Python 3 does not let you compare mismatching types)

Comment: Can you help me figure out how to compare the right things? Do I need to somehow make the input an integer rather than a string?

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Answer (score 1):

raw_input returns a string, not a number. Before the comparison, you need to turn it into int or float.

Btw, if you are starting with python, go for 3 instead of 2. 2 is already EOL and support for libraries is starting to decrease.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an integer and a string.
You need to cast the string to an integer using `int()`.
So, you could for example do something like this

`grade = int(raw_input("What was your score?"))`

Of course, this would then leave you with the problem that that (ugly) concatenation you are doing to display your output message would stop working (as you cannot concatenate strings and integers).
Rather than directly using string concatenation, it's 99% of the times better to use `format`, like this:

`print "For a score of {}, your grade is an A".format(grade)`

Answer (score -1):

grade = int(input("Enter your score"))

use python 3.